# preserving component state across multiple request cycles

Tags: java, wicket, state

Question about component state management with Apache Wicket 1.4.x

I have a bookmarkable, stateful page that contains a form with a set search criteria. The user search for items matching the selected criteria and then navigate away from the page (to a detailed item view, for instance). At some point of time the user can come back to the search page using a bookmarkable link. I would like the last search criteria to be pre-selected as a default choice. However, it appears that `BookmarkablePageRequestTarget` aways creates a new instance of the target page in its `#respond(RequestCycle)` method, thus losing previous state (the bean backing the search form).

Naturally, I could manually manage the form state and store it in the `WebSession` subclass, but I am wondering whether or not there might be a better way to preserve component state across multiple request cycles, like making Wicket re-use the existing instance of the target Page? Ideally this would work with bookmarkble links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount your bookmarkable page with [HybridUrlCodingStrategy](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket/1.4.0/wicket-1.4.0-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/wicket/request/target/coding/HybridUrlCodingStrategy.html) or its subclass. This will append a page identifier to the URL and ensure that the back button works with bookmarkable links.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the state of a component is stored in the component instance itself. (Either directly in it, or indirectly, in models.)

So all you really need to do is to create a link that points to the search page **instance**, or call `setResponsePage()` with the page instance or something similar, depending on how you're redirecting the user.

Normally, you shouldn't even touch request targets at all, unless the actual scenario is much more complex than the one you're describing.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but can one create a link to a particular instance of a Page, and more importantly, how can one obtain a reference to an instance of a particular Page?

Comment: @oleg Sorry, I didn't realise that was the problem. To create a link to an existing Page, you can use the [PageLink](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/PageLink.html) class. And the reference you can just pass it along. So when you open your details page from your search page, you basically pass `this` and then when the details page has to link back, you can use that reference.

Comment: Right. The trouble is that the user can navigate away from the detailed view to a whole number of different areas of application, not just search. It is just not feasible to drag around a reference to an instance of SearchPage across the entire application.

Comment: @oleg In that case the easiest thing indeed is to store your form model object in the web session. It's not as bad as it sounds. You just extend `WebSession` and add a field plus getter/setter for your model object and in your form you have a `Model` that takes it's value from there.